# Is there any reason to use NFS 3 over version 4.2?

Tags: networking, nfs, performance, nfsv4

Consider a work environment with 100gbps type Infiniband switches, running on enterprise class servers having 512 GB of RAM and larger, with the operating system being RHEL 8.7 or very close to it.

When setting up NFS between servers, is the latest NFS vers=4.2 the best choice?  Is there any reason when using NFSv3 with proto=UDP is ever better than NFS vers=4.2 with proto=tcp/udp/rdma ?

I am particularly interested in this regarding many cluster nodes mounting a `/data` folder from a head node for read/write; what is the logical nfs choice if the goal is performance?

I have found this, dated 2008, which is presumably for vers=4.0 and not 4.2, that makes the statement *there is no clear performance advantage to moving from NFSv3 to NFSv4*.

https://www.linux.com/news/benchmarking-nfsv3-vs-nfsv4-file-operation-performance/

also

https://www.techtarget.com/searchenterprisedesktop/definition/Network-File-System

*Some reviews of NFSv4 and NFSv4.1 suggest that these versions have limited bandwidth and scalability and that NFS slows down during heavy network traffic. The bandwidth and scalability issue is reported to have improved with NFSv4.2.  This was last updated in April 2022*

Comment: One reason I would use v4.2 over v3 is kerberos, but I assume you are not using it.

Comment: correct not using kerberos, although there is an obscure security requirement wanting kerberos done with nfs I have no plan to implement kerberos.  Just looking for best perfomance & reliability on an internal isolated LAN of a cluster on infiniband.

Comment: I am also of the opinion if you're going to do NFS why would you not want the latest vers=4.2 AND do RDMA, given the definition of rdma and the performance that provides especially if the cpu is crunching numbers running software why have the extra overhead of cpu cycles to deal with NFS tcp/udp.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong here.